# Cant execute python program

Tags: python, execute

I recently purchased **Learn Python the Hard Way** and the first thing that I have to do is execute hello world program in python. The book asks me to write out the code in a Notepad ++ file, to save it as ex1.py, and to run it in the Python terminal by typing "python ex1.py". When I do this however, I get back an error.

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
  python ex1.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone please help me with this problem? I am very interested in learning Python but these kind of issues discourage me. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Post your code, and please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looks like you are typing `python ex1.py` into the Python interpreter, and not the command line shell.

Answer (score 0):

`python ex1.py` - you should be running this from the command prompt, it looks like you're trying to run it from within a python shell. For example:

```
C:\pythonstuff> python ex1.py
```

Comment: Yep, this should do. You can launch a terminal pressing Windows key + R and typing cmd. Press Enter and voilà, the scary white-on-black window!